# Controlling a robot through a game steering wheel

Tags: ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using the joy_node of the joy package to control a robot car in V-REP. Now I want to control the robot with a game steering wheel. Is there any package in ROS for this? Otherwise, how do I do this? I already have some knowledge of ROS and V-REP, but I do not know how to read the data sent by the steering wheel driver. I want to use a force feedback steering wheel and a set of pedals. I'm using ROS kinetic and ubuntu 16.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280826/controlling-a-robot-through-a-game-steering-wheel/) by [Ednilson](https://answers.ros.org/users/33423/ednilson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-01-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-01-25**:
This might be an obvious question, but have you tried using the joy node with the steering wheel? I though they all used the same standard interface?

**Comment by [Ednilson](https://answers.ros.org/users/33423/ednilson/) on 2018-02-01**:
This is another problem. I still do not have the steering wheel. I would like to receive some tip from some steering wheel that is compatible with some existing ROS package and that accepts force feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It doesn't look (as far as I can see) there are any ros nodes dedicated to steering wheels. [This Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/6j7qs5/how_is_steering_wheel_support_in_linux/) has a good discussion on linux compatible ones and links to some git repos. You may have to dive in and make your own node for this.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0